# How to organise Ansible roles?

Tags: ansible, roles

Let's say I have 2 group of hosts that have similar needs in my structure, but they don't share all the same packages installed, for example. Like this:

generators (host group) needs:

- rpm A
- rpm B
- rpm C

executors (another host group) needs:

- rpm A
- rpm B

How should I organise my Ansible roles? One way of doing it is having:

```
generators-role
    - main.yml
        - package install
            - rpm A
            - rpm B
            - rpm C

executors-role
    - main.yml
        - package install
            - rpm A
            - rpm B
```

The problem with that is that if I need to change something regarding packa installation, I have to change it in 2 places. I could go with something like:

```
packages1-role
    - main.yml
        - package install
            - rpm A
            - rpm B

packages2-role
    - main.yml
        - package install
            - rpm C
```

And then:

```
generators-playbook
    - roles:
        - packages1-role
        - packages2-role

executors-playbook
    - roles:
        - packages2-role
```

But in this case I really would need to have a strong reason to group RPM beyond "they belong in the same group of hosts". And also I still can get in the same problem as in the first example.

I considered also using tags or conditionals based on variables passed to the roles, but that seems a bit hacky, or at least that is what I understood from the Ansible docs.

So, any hints on what's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer ansible best pratices (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are 2 other ways to do this:

1) Use a generic `packages` role and pass the rpm to install to the role as a var

```
generators-playbook
   - roles:
       - { role: packages, packages: ["rpmA","rpmB"] }
executor-playbook
   - roles:
       - { role: packages, packages: ["rpmC"] }
```

2) Use 1 role per package, and then including the correct role in each host group

```
generators-playbook
   - roles: 
       - rpmA
       - rpmB
executors-playbook
   - roles:
       - rpmC
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: way number 1 is more or less what I meant when I wrote "conditionals based on variables passed to the roles". It probably works well but I think this does not change the fact that I would need to change the list of packages installed in multiple places if I needed to add/remove packages from my playbooks.

Comment: I tend to not think to a role as a single package install, to me a role is a sort of bigger entity ( eg. an nginx role will install ngnix package and configure it based on group/host vars ). I'd probably try to expand the 'package' role to something bigger that effectively does something with the installed package. Otherwise the packages role makes sense